# Projeto SpringBoot da 'started' mas não consigo chamar APIs no Postman

Tags: api, spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa, postman

O projeto da start mas quando vou chamar no postman nada volta, nem da erro. É como se o projeto não tivesse subido! 
No pom.xml estão as dependências: jpa, mysql e web. Não mexi nada nelas.
Meu pacotes estão separados em entities, repository, service e controller.

Abaixo como está meu application.properties
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

log: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: todas suas classes estão no mesmo pacote, ou você está utilizando pacotes diferentes?

Comment: tem como colocar o log de start do teu spring-boot?

Comment: Os pacotes estão separados. Adicionei na pergunta...
Também adicionei o log

Comment: você usou o @ComponetScan para localizar seus pacotes?

Comment: Não usei, não conheço essa anotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloque a anotação @ComponentScan(value = "br.com.seupacote.controller.ou.etc") na sua classe de Application.

exemplo:

```
package br.com.meuprojeto.exemplo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;



@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(value = "br.com.meuprojeto.controller")
public class ExemploApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExemploApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```